# Why might this [Swift] NSObject.addObserver registration not be calling func observeValueForKeyPath() as expected?

Tags: swift, xcode6, addobserver

Problematic code follows. [I hope that] the problem is wholly outlined in the question above. Thanks in advance. MJB.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var some_string:NSString = "one"

    func application ( application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]? ) -> Bool
    {
        println("init...")
        self.addObserver( self, forKeyPath: "some_string", options: nil, context: nil )
        self.some_string = "two"
        return true
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath ( keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> )
    {
        println("observeValueForKeyPath...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8), you need to use the `dynamic` keyword to enable KVO for that property:

```
dynamic var some_string : NSString = "one"
```

Also, the class must inherit from `NSObject` to make this work, though in your case that is a given with `UIResponder`.

Comment: Thank you Erik, and thanks for being gracefully passive-aggressive. Sometimes we all need a bit of a poke in the face to make up us sharpen up. Apple docs, got it.

Comment: Oh I wasn't trying to be, just giving you reference material. I had to look it up to find this gem out myself!